# Play Framework Java 2.2 Google Maps Places API

Tags: java, json, google-maps, playframework

I have a problem with the Play Framework 2.2 in Java.

I calling the Google Map Places API and I want the result in JSON.

This is my code:

```
Promise<JsonNode> request = WS.url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")
   .setQueryParameter("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362")
   .setQueryParameter("key", "my_key")
   .setQueryParameter("name", "")
   .setQueryParameter("language", "DE")
   .setQueryParameter("rankby", "distance")
   .setQueryParameter("types", "grocery_or_supermarket")
   .post("content");
```

Does someone have an idea how to put this into JSON? I tried several methods (even with GET instead of POST), however it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used the play.libs.Json.toJson built in functionality. Below is some code i used to turn some database results to json. I that helps.

```
public static Result getClubs() {
 List<Club> clubs = models.Club.find.all();
 return ok(play.libs.Json.toJson(clubs));
}
```

Regards,

John